# Dynamic SECRET_KEY in Django disadvantages

Tags: python, django, security

I just started learning Django and I'm wondering what the drawbacks of using a randomly generated SECRET-KEY would be. So far I've started with using this code...

```
from pathlib import Path import random, string

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'. BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# Randomized security key size = 100 SECRET_KEY = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase
+ string.punctuation + string.hexdigits + string.digits, k = size))
```

For now, this seems to work well for a simple blog that I made but I'm wondering what drawbacks this might have in other uses and if there are better ways of making the key secure.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's not going to work if you are using a production setup with multiple worker processes.

Comment: Or if the process get's restarted hashed/encrypted values won't be readable and will become invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should indeed use a random-generated secret key, but it shouldn't be dynamically generated in the settings, as rotating the key invalidates active sessions, messages and tokens. [From the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#std-setting-SECRET_KEY):

> The secret key is used for:
>
> - All [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/sessions/) if you are using any other session backend than **django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache**, or are using the default
>   **[get_session_auth_hash()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractBaseUser.get_session_auth_hash)**.
> - All [messages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/messages/) if you are using **[CookieStorage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/messages/#django.contrib.messages.storage.cookie.CookieStorage)** or **[FallbackStorage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/messages/#django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage)**.
> - All **[PasswordResetView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetView)** tokens.
> - Any usage of [cryptographic signing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/signing/), unless a different key is provided.
>
> If you rotate your secret key, all of the above will be invalidated.
> Secret keys are not used for passwords of users and key rotation will
> not affect them.

**Note**: Don't use `random.choices()` to generate a secret key, as it is not cryptographically secure. You can use the [secrets module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html) for that:

```py
import secrets
import string

choices = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + "<>()[]*?@!#~,.;"
key = "".join(secrets.choice(choices) for n in range(100))
```